# Return custom exceptions in case of failure with RxJava + Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a repository class that must return this: `Observable<List<SomeObject>`,
I do this:

```
 @Override
    public Observable<List<SomeObject>> getAllById(Long id) {
        if (!AndroidUtils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext))
            return Observable.error(new NoNetworkConnectionException());

        return mRestService.get(id);
    }
```

This approach works normally, the problem is I want to return custom exceptions
in case of failures, but I don't know the best way to do this with rxjava.

So far, the only solution that works is something like that:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<SomeObject>> getAllById(Long id) {
    if (!AndroidUtils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext))
        return Observable.error(new NoNetworkConnectionException());

    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        mRestService.get(id).subscribe(new Observer<List<SomeObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (e instanceof HttpException  && ((HttpException) e).code() == 401)
                    subscriber.onError(new UnathorizedException());
                else
                    subscriber.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<SomeObject> objects) {
                subscriber.onNext(objects);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I know that is not a good thing to use Observable.create, but I can't figure out
another way to do this.

RestService is this:

```
public interface RestService {

    @GET("objects/{id}")
    Observable<List<SomeObject>> get(@Path("id") Long id);
}
```

If anyone knows a better approach, please tell me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You can use the operator `onErrorResumeNext` to map your exception to another one.

```
mRestService.get(id)
            .onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
                if (e instanceof HttpException  && ((HttpException) e).code() == 401)
                    return Observable.error(new UnathorizedException());
                else
                    return Observable.error(e);
            })
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay to give a feedback. I tested and works great. So, any exceptions that might occur in the request end up calling onErrorResumeNext()? There are any drawbacks with this implementation, like the one using Observable.create()?

Comment: Thank You so Much! I just know about this

Answer (score 3):

I did this in a project by adding an interceptor when creating the rest service. This way the errors are checked before the request reaches your rest service.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new ErrorInterceptor());

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .build();
```

The ErrorInterceptor class looks like

```
public class ErrorInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(originalRequest);

        if (response.code() >= 400) {
            throwError(response);
            return response;
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }

    private void throwError (Response response) throws IOException {
        ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
        BufferedSource source = responseBody.source();
        source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); // Buffer the entire body.
        Buffer buffer = source.buffer();

        Charset charset = UTF8;
        MediaType contentType = responseBody.contentType();
        if (contentType != null) {
            charset = contentType.charset(UTF8);
        }

        if (responseBody.contentLength() != 0) {
            String responseJSON = buffer.clone().readString(charset);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.getType();
            ErrorResponse error = null;
            try {
                error = gson.fromJson(responseJSON, type);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                int a = 1;
            }
            if (error != null && error.hasErrors())
                throw ErrorMapper.mapError(error.getFirstError());
        }
    }
}
```

And my ErrorResponse class

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private List<Error> errors;

    public boolean hasErrors () {
        return errors != null && errors.size() > 0;
    }

    public Error getFirstError() {
        if (errors == null || errors.size() == 0) return null;
        return errors.get(0);
    }
}
```

In my ErrorMapper I just check the error message against a set of possible messages from the server and create a new Error containing the message to display on the client.

I'm just checking the first error here, but you should easily be able to adopt it to multiple errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
    RestService restService = Mockito.mock(RestService.class);

    Observable<List<Object>> networkExOrEmpty = isNetworkAvailable() ?
            Observable.empty() :
            Observable.error(new NoNetworkConnectionException());

    Observable<List<Object>> resultOrEx = restService
            .getAllById(42L)
            .materialize()
            .map(res -> {
                if (res.isOnError()) {
                    Throwable err = res.getThrowable();
                    if (err instanceof HttpException && ((HttpException) err).code() == 401) {
                        return Notification.createOnError(new UnauthrizedException());
                    } else {
                        return Notification.createOnError(err);
                    }
                } else {
                    return res;
                }
            }).dematerialize();


    Observable<List<Object>> result = networkExOrEmpty.concatWith(resultOrEx);
```

Start with `Observable` which emits either Error or nothing, depending on network conectivity state, then concatenate it with result from `Retrofit` service. `Observable.materialize()` allows one to act on error items: push appropriate exception downstream, and pass non-error notifications as is.